# AD Roaming Profiles via VPN not synchronizing

Tags: active-directory, vpn, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, roaming-profile

I want to create local Client-VMs (Windows 8.1) for our developers. These should connect to our VPN and login on our AD server (Windows Server 2012 R2). I'm using serverside profiles for this so that all settings (e.g. configuration on IDEs like Visual Studio) are stored on the server. We can keep backups of them so that nothing is lost e.g. when the Client-VM crashes because of a disk failture and other possible problems.

At the beginning this is working, but now the synchronisation of the userprofiles isn't working any more. I connect to the VPN at the login screen of the Client-VM and I get logged in without any errors, but e.g. the user-librarys are not synchronized. When I logout, I get an errormessage that my remote profile can't be full synchronized.

In the Logs of the Client I found the following (Bold parts are analogously translated to English because the VM is a German Windows installation, the rest is 1:1 copied from the event-log):

> **The roaming profile could not be fully updated. Details can be found in the previous events.**

---

> **We saw that our registry-file is used from other applications or services. The file will be     >unloaded now. Applications and services which are using the file will may not work correctly any     >more. No user interaction is required**
>
> DETAIL - 
>   1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1107009087-2515811915-3103359273->1105_Classes:
>   Process 840 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S->1-5-21-1107009087-2515811915-3103359273-1105_CLASSES
>
> ---
>
> **We saw that our registry-file is used from other applications or services. The file will be >unloaded now. Applications and services which are using the file will may not work correctly any >more. No user interaction is required**
>
> DETAIL - 
>   2 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1107009087-2515811915-3103359273-1105:
>   Process 1296 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1107009087-2515811915-3103359273-1105
>   Process 840 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1107009087-2515811915-3103359273-1105
>
> ---
>
> "CoID={2ED062F2-1B38-46D0-BA3E-F4964F86AB0A}: **The user "SYSTEM" choosed a connection named "VPN", but the connection was disconnected. The reasoncode which was given by the disconnect was 830.**

The sequence corresponds to the eventlog. I think it's very strange that the VPN-Connection was closed *before* the sync-error of the roaming profile occurs (there are 9 seconds between these two messages). I think that's the problem why the roaming profile can't be synchronized, but it can't explain why it seems that the profile is also not synchronisized on login.

I'm not sure if the log-entrys about the registry have something to do with this issue because it seems that they're about something other (e.g. spoolsv.exe is about the queue for printers) and there is also an info that no action is required (not sure if this is really true).

So my question is: What is the problem here? Why is the sync of roaming profiles not working any more? It's very wired because at the beginning it worked fine. Then I created some GPOs for excluding  folders with bulk stuff (e.g. downloads) and since them the problem is there. I also disabled the GPOs (also ALL for testing, including the the default ones) but it's still not working.

And I created a new account in hope that this is a account-specific problem, but nothing changes.

Comment: At the client machine, if you do a gpudpate, is it successful?

Comment: Yes it is, I already tried it with the /force parameter but the problem is still there like before...